# A question about sudo and pass the password to command

Tags: sudo, su

Most user said is easy to pass password for sudo command using this cli

```
sudo -S <<< "yourpassord" yourcommand
```

or

```
echo "yourpassword|yourcommand
```

Those cli works for a lot of commands(mkdir, touch, etc) but for some commands like su make problems

```
sudo -S <<< "yourpassword" su - youruser
-su: line 1: youpassword: command not found

echo youpassword|sudo -S su - youruser 
-su: line 1: youpassword: command not found
```

How to resolve?
Actually I use this workaround

```
echo yourpassword | sudo -v -S
sudo su - youruser #now work because password is in memory
```

Someone know a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer, so I put as a temporary solution this one

```
echo yourpassword | sudo -v -S
sudo su - youruser #now work because password is in memory
```